# How to use Object.create for inheritance within modules in node.js

Tags: node.js, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance, object-create

I have a module Vehicle that contains general vehicle info. I have another module Car, which adds more functionality to Vehicle object.

```
// Pseudo code only. The final functions do not have to resemble this
var vehicle = require('vehicle')
vehicle.terrain = 'Land'
var car = vehicle.createCar()
// car and anotherCar will have unique Car-related values,
// but will use the same Vehicle info
var anotherCar = vehicle.createCar()
```

I am looking at using Object.create for the Car module, but not sure where the Object.create calls should go.

- Should I have a constructor in the Car module that takes an instance of a Vehicle object and does an Object.create with the Vehicle instance as the prototype?
- Or should the Object.create happen in a function on the Vehicle object, like createCar? My issue with this way, is Car should care that it's derived from Vehicle, Vehicle shouldn't know Car requires that.
- Or even if Object.create is the right approach.

Please, any examples and best practices would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**

I changed the example to better reflect the inheritance problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

imo, you're describing a builder pattern rather than inheritance I think -- I wouldn't use object.create for this. A VehicleBuilder is responsible for constructing an object that has certain properties associated with it.

```
var builder = new VehicleBuilder();
builder.terrain = 'Land';
builder.wheelCount = 2;
builder.color = "blue";
var motorcycle = builder.createVehicle();
```

It might use something like:

```
VehicleBuilder.prototype.createVehicle = function(){
    var me = this;
    return new Vehicle({
         color: me.color,
         terrain: me.terrain,
         wheelCount: me.wheelCount
    });
}
```

If you look at the typical inheritance pattern in js, its something much more well defined and uses two primary patterns in node. One is util.inherits. Its code is simple: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/util.js#L423-428

```
exports.inherits = function(ctor, superCtor) {
  ctor.super_ = superCtor;
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
    constructor: { value: ctor, enumerable: false }
  });
};
```

And the second is calling the parent constructor in the child class constructor.

```
function ChildClass(){
    SuperClass.call(this); // here
}
```

Example: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/stream.js#L25-28

So instead of a vehicle taking a bunch of properties or another object in its constructor, you use the prototype chain and the constructor to define custom subclass behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the samples. I ended up going with util.inherits, but like the idea of a builder.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a different approach

```
// foo.js
var topic = require("topic");
topic.name = "History";
topic.emit("message");
topic.on("message", function() { /* ... */ });

// topic.js
var events = require("events");
var Topic = function() {

};

// inherit from eventEmitter
Topic.prototype = new events.EventEmitter();
exports.module = new Topic;
```

You have a good [`EventEmitter`](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.8/api/events.html) to do message passing for you. I recommend you just extend the prototype of `Topic` with it.

Comment: I changed my example to better reflect the basic inheritance I'm trying to achieve and how to use Object.create for that. The original Topic/Publish/Subscribe example was too confusing with node's concept of event emitting.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use js native prototype based inheritance?  Expose your constructor directly using module.exports:

```
//vehicle.js
module.exports = function() {
  //make this a vehicle somehow
}
```

Then:

```
// Pseudo code only. The final functions do not have to resemble this
var Vehicle = require('vehicle')
Vehicle.terrain = 'Land'
var car = new Vehicle()
// car and anotherCar will have unique Car-related values,
// but will use the same Vehicle info
var anotherCar = new Vehicle()
```

Comment: Nope.  You just made all vehicles into land vehicles, not just the cars.

Comment: The question didn't suggest that the vehicles aren't supposed to all be land vehicles.  And for that matter, you're making a lot of assumptions about what Vehicle.terrain even does.